# Как пересобрать Pyinstaller?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

При компиляции exe файла при помощи Pyinstaller защитник винды очень сильно ругается.

На киберфоруме был похожий вопрос, в ответах рекомендуют пересобрать пакет.

https://www.cyberforum.ru/python-ide/thread2837483.html

И вот собственно гайд как это сделать, вопрос в том сработает ли это?
Если другие способы компиляции exe?

В чем смысл пересборки?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Мамкины хакеры пишут на Python свои зловредные скрипты, и собирают в exe с помощью pyinstaller, в итоге антивирусы начинают ругаться на все, что собрано с помощью pyinstaller. Смысл пересборки в том, что после пересборки лоадер может немного отличаться (другая версия компилятора может влиять, например), и возможно антивирусы будут ругаться не так сильно. Поможет или нет - как повезет.

Comment: Можно попробовать nuitka вместо pyinstaller использовать, там вообще все в си транслируется, потом компилируется в настоящий exe. Вероятность того, что антивирусы будут ругаться сильно ниже.

Comment: Еще добавлю. Проблема старого лоадера в том, что все программы, собранные с помощью pyinstaller - это один и тот же exe файл (лоадер) с приклеенным в конце zip архивом с python кодом и другими включенными файлами. Для антивирусов это все один и тот же exe по сути. После пересборки лоадера exe файл будет немного другим, но я бы сильно не надеялся на то, что это решит проблемы с антивирусами.

Comment: @student2023 "При компиляции exe файла при помощи Pyinstaller защитник винды очень сильно ругается.", "скажите защитнику" остынь братан это свои.

Comment: @Александр Самый доходчивый ответ, как никак.

Comment: Есть случаи когда производители ПО просят отключить антивирус при установке, в вашем случае нужно указать в настройках защитника что этот файл безопасный, вариаций как это сделать много.